# Should each post tag have its own mongo collection, if the user can tab to each tag?

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

The database is MongoDB, not SQL, and that isn't going to change.

Suppose you have an app that allows users to post questions and then tag them with a single subject: math, science, english, history.

Also, on the nav, each subject has its own tab that will display questions that are tagged with the corresponding subject.

Since the display of questions by tag is essential to the app, what is the fastest way to retrieve this data?

Possibilities:
(1) Leave the tags as a single field in the questions collection. Problem: Would have to search through every question, then search through the tags field, to find the relevant tags.

(2) A tag collection, with a field for each subject. Problem: if the number of questions grow too large (approx 20,000 posts), Mongo won't work. From the Mongo docs (http://blog.mongodb.org/post/35133050249/mongodb-for-the-php-mind-part-3):

> With document design you need to consider two things: scale and
>   search. ScaleMongoDB Documents have a limit of 16MB, which although
>   sounds quite small, can accommodate thousands of documents. However if
>   you are expecting 20,000 comments per post on a high traffic website,
>   or your comments are unlimited in size, then embedding might not work
>   well for you.

This seems to leave...
(3) A separate collection for each tag. Is (3) best in this case?

Answer (score 1):

From the (rather rudimentary) spec you give, I'd go for a single collection for the documents, where each document contains an array of tags:

```
{
   _id: "whatever",
   content: "the question",
   tags: [ "this", "that", "and another tag" ]
   ...
}
```

Then, for efficient querying by tag, set a multi-key index on the tags.
See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/#multikey-index